# Is it possible to create a (triggered) Automation through the soap api

Tags: soap-api, automation

gets triggered by a file drop, (step 1) create a file transfer that decrypts the file and puts it in safehouse, (step 2) import file from safehouse to DE.
I can do this through the ui and it works perfectly, but the soap calls just fail.
I've banged my head too many times so I'm finally posting.. thanks to anyone who replies

This is the request I made:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1">
         <wsse:UsernameToken>
            <wsse:Username></wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password></wsse:Password>
         </wsse:UsernameToken>
      </wsse:Security>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <CreateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <Options/>
         <Objects xsi:type="Automation">
            <Name>test_rohan_quaero_2_step</Name>
            <CustomerKey>test_rohan_quaero_2_step</CustomerKey>
            <Description>test_rohan_quaero_2_step</Description>
            <AutomationTasks>
               <AutomationTask>
                  <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
                  <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
                  <Name>test_rohan_quaero_2_step_AT</Name>
                  <Activities>
                     <Activity>
                        <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
                        <ObjectID>df216a2d-0d1e-4796-ad5f-b955f965828e</ObjectID>
                        <Name>test_rohan_quaero_2_step_AT_FT</Name>
                     </Activity>
                  </Activities>
               </AutomationTask>
            </AutomationTasks>
            <AutomationType>triggered</AutomationType>
         </Objects>
      </CreateRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

the issue is I used an existing FileTransfer object, I want to create it on the fly

the response was ok

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <soap:Header>
        <wsa:Action>CreateResponse</wsa:Action>
        <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:811ff19b-3cd9-4584-a1a9-12f998055d6c</wsa:MessageID>
        <wsa:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:046c33a0-97b0-425a-9d5c-8c1506190bfc</wsa:RelatesTo>
        <wsa:To>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:To>
        <wsse:Security>
            <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-6347d97b-1221-4c99-8b85-7183996c9beb">
                <wsu:Created>2019-03-27T06:53:14Z</wsu:Created>
                <wsu:Expires>2019-03-27T06:58:14Z</wsu:Expires>
            </wsu:Timestamp>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <CreateResponse xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <Results>
                <StatusCode>OK</StatusCode>
                <OrdinalID>0</OrdinalID>
                <NewID>0</NewID>
                <NewObjectID>8db81fd1-b849-4b4a-94bb-97844d3b42d0</NewObjectID>
                <Object xsi:type="Automation">
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                    <PartnerProperties>
                        <Name>AutomationType</Name>
                        <Value>Triggered</Value>
                    </PartnerProperties>
                    <ObjectID>8db81fd1-b849-4b4a-94bb-97844d3b42d0</ObjectID>
                    <CustomerKey>test_rohan_quaero_2_step</CustomerKey>
                    <IsPlatformObject>false</IsPlatformObject>
                    <Name>test_rohan_quaero_2_step</Name>
                    <Description>test_rohan_quaero_2_step</Description>
                    <AutomationTasks>
                        <AutomationTask>
                            <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                            <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                            <Activities>
                                <Activity>
                                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                                    <ObjectID>df216a2d-0d1e-4796-ad5f-b955f965828e</ObjectID>
                                    <Name>test_rohan_quaero_2_step_AT_FT</Name>
                                    <Description />
                                    <IsActive>false</IsActive>
                                    <Definition>
                                        <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                                        <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                                    </Definition>
                                    <Sequence>0</Sequence>
                                </Activity>
                            </Activities>
                        </AutomationTask>
                    </AutomationTasks>
                    <IsActive>true</IsActive>
                    <AutomationType>Triggered</AutomationType>
                </Object>
            </Results>
            <RequestID>26434351-0842-44ee-9da3-43f47d6d6dd3</RequestID>
            <OverallStatus>OK</OverallStatus>
        </CreateResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

but the file drop is undefined, and it didn't use the existing file transfer object either(fine with that, want to create it sequentially or in parallel anyway), this is what the api is generating:

[image]

And this is what I want the api to generate

[image]

Comment: Can you please share the SOAP payloads you have been trying to use so far?

Comment: @LukasLunow updated the request I made, I've only tried adding the first step cos even that fails